# Looping advanced filters through columns with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite the novice when it comes to vba so bear with me.  I have a data set that is variable in column and row length.  Each column contains a range of data that I'm trying to use the advanced filter to put out unique cells.

```
sub uniques()
    dim i as integer
    dim numcol as integer
    dim rng as range
    dim ws as worksheet
    dim ws2 as worksheet

    set ws = sheets("Sheet1") 'data
    set ws2 = sheets("Sheet2") 'paste unique per column data

    numcol = activesheet.usedrange.columns.count

    for i = 1 to numcol

        set rng = ws.columns(i)
        set rng2 = ws2.columns(i)

        ws.rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws2.rng2, unique=True

    Next

end sub
```

I've tried a few different ways but I think this one is the closest.  I am eager to learn so any tips are greatly appreciate.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question? Does the code throw an error? Does it not output what you expect?  Note that you should probably use a worksheet name instead of `Activesheet` for `numcol`, either `ws.UsedRange` or `ws2.UsedRange` to make sure the column count is from the sheet you want.

Comment: I apologize for the delay and not being specific.  It kept throw an error on the advanced filter.  I was actually able to work it out - set edit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my problem was properly setting the copy and paste ranges in the loop.  This has worked.  I appreciate the comment.

```html
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim numcol As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'data
    Set ws2 = Sheets.Add 

    numcol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.count
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange

    For i = 1 To numcol
        rng.Columns(i).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,  CopyToRange:=ws2.Columns(i), Unique:=True
    Next

End Sub
```